# Find Anagram in Pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word1': ['elvis', 'lease', 'admirer'], 'word2': ['lives', 'sale', 'married']})
```

how can I add a third column that returns True or False depending on whether the two words in the same row are an anagram or not?

I have written this function, which returns an error when I apply it to the df.

```
def anagram(word1, word2):

    word1_lst = [l for l in word1]
    word2_lst = [i for i in word2] 

    return sorted(word1_lst) == sorted(word2_lst)


df['Anagram'] = df.apply(anagram(df['word1'], df['word2']), axis = 1)
```

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are calling `df.apply()` with the args

`anagram(df['word1'], df['word2')` which is a bool, not a function

and

`axis = 1`

To fix, alter your function like this:

```py
def anagram(row):
    word1_lst = [l for l in row['word1']]
    word2_lst = [i for i in row['word2']]

    return sorted(word1_lst) == sorted(word2_lst)
```

then call the method with the function name, not the result

```py
df['Anagram'] = df.apply(anagram, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word1': ['elvis', 'lease', 'admirer'], 'word2': ['lives', 'sale', 'married']})
df['Anagram'] = df.word1.apply(sorted) == df.word2.apply(sorted)
```